A "django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation" error is occurring despite setting everything up correctly
Currently attempting to serve all of my static files via whitenoise.
Funnily enough, the function itself works a treat. It seeks out all the directories labelled static in all of my Django apps. However, why is Django consistently returning the django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation exception in my traceback, and why is this returning this just one css file.
Logic would dictate that seeing as this css file is among other .css files in the same directory, Django seems to have some sort of personal vendetta against this one file.
On the face it it, what Django is doing is completely illogical.
My settings are as follows:
pip install whitenoise
settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
.....
"whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
.....
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ....
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/assets/brand-assets",
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/assets/images",
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/assets/vectors",
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/assets/videos",
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/css",
    BASE_DIR / "static/libraries/js",
    BASE_DIR / "static/main",
    BASE_DIR / "legal/static",
    BASE_DIR / "blog/static",
    BASE_DIR / "events/static",
    BASE_DIR / "careers/static",
    BASE_DIR / "media/static",
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

My file directory is as follows:
PROJECT NAME-|
  Root-|
    settings.py
  careers-|
    static-|
      careers.css
  media-|
    static-|
      media.css
  blog-|
    static-|
      blog.css
  legal-|
    static-|
      legal.css
  static-|
    main-|
      xxx.css
      xxx.css
    libraries-|
      css # <- location of the offending css file
      js
      assets-|
        vectors
        videos
        images
        brand-assets
  

"careers","media","blog","legal" are my Django apps.
The "offending" .css file, transparent-nav.css, is located in the BASE_DIR+/static/libraries/css directory. Upon running python manage.py collectstaticthe trace back is as follows:
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\Users\xxx\xxx\<base_dir>\libraries\css\transparent-nav.css) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - xxx\<base_dir>\staticfiles)
As you can see, the offending file is NOT located outside of the base path component because this directory has been set up in the settings.py file under STATICFILES_DIRS, so why is Django telling me that it is? It makes absolutely no sense.
Could it be a cache issue?
Just to give you an idea of who clearly broken this is, I even changed:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
to
STATIC_URL = 'dsfsjdfhjkdfhjksdfhjksd/'
It didn't even pick up the fact that there was not even a file named dsfsjdfhjkdfhjksdfhjksd/ but it sill threw the same exception.

Clear .pyc files for a change.

How would one clear .pyc files? Cheers.

It’s usually a folder that Python automatically creates when you run a python program.

@ChukwujiobiCanon SAlso, do you any mistake in my code which could cause this? I don't but its good to have a second pair of eyes on the case. Thanks

@ChukwujiobiCanon Oh yes, I see them, but how would I clear them? Or do you mean delete?

Yea. And also changing STATIC_URL only affects the rendered HTML.
